# Pentaho Spoon: Cannot split string in JavaScript Step

Tags: javascript, string, split, pentaho-spoon, geokettle

I am trying to use the JavaScript step in order to extract the first part of a string of the input field "name". An example entry for the field "name" would be: "14 Ri.". And I want to extract the "14" out of the string. For this, I have tried to do this with the split, substr and replace-function. But none of this works as I am always getting the exception "arrayoutofbounds".

I want to pass all input fields to all output fields, except for the name. For the name I only want to pass the extracted part of the string (in the example this would be "14").

In the picture below, you can see my javascript step interface + code + error:
[image]

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This should be true:

```
'14 R1'.split(" ")[0] === '14'
```

Make sure that 'name' is set

Comment: In that case you probably have an error somewhere else. This works 100% you can try it on some online javascript executor.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the name may be empty or null:

```
if(name)
    name = name.split(" ")[0];
```